M/V Multiplicative NT : Theorem 11.3 and the Siegel zero
Two questions regarding Theorem 11.3 in the book of Montgomery & Vaughan Multiplicative Number Theory on the section "Case 4. Quadratic $χ$, real zeros.":
First the book supposes there are two real zeros such that $β_0 ≤ β_1 < 1$. Then after some calculations it arrives at $1 − β_0 ≥ \dfrac{1}{6c_2 \log 4q}$.
Q.1) $1 − β_0 ≥ \dfrac{1}{6c_2 \log 4q}$ is of the same form as the first three cases: it implies if $β_0$ is a zero of $L(s,χ)$ then it does not lie in the zero free region. But the statement of the theorem says that the zero free region may contain this real zero. How are these two consistent? In other words, roughly speaking, in the first three cases the same $"≥"$ occurs and then conclusion follows since $"<"$ is for $R_q$.
Q.2) When assuming $β_0 ≤ β_1 < 1$, $β_1$ drops out in the lines of calculations. The proof was supposed to show that there is at most one real zero. How does the conclusion of the proof show that there is no more than one real zero? Some kind of an irrelevant conclusion or an ambiguous proof (?)
My questions may seem rudimentary but I can't figure them out maybe because the textbook is not as clear as Titchmarsh's.
